# JQuery Scroll slow and fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a function where, when a user scrolls to a certain scrolltop position, it does something specific for that point.

```
$('#main').scroll(function(e) 
{
  if $('#main').scrollTop() == x)
  {
  //DO SOMETHING
  }

});
```

The trouble I'm finding is, when I scroll nice as slowly, the scroll increment is regular 1,2,3,4 etc and all works correctly, but when I scroll with any speed, the increment is non-uniform and so I often miss the specific point I want to 'Do Something'.

I can't use a >= in the condition as there are lots of the triggers.

Is there anyway I can get the uniform increments (more precision, I guess) of the scroll?

Thanks

Comment: I'd still say your best bet is to look for a point in range. Why exactly can't you?

Comment: I can't use ranges because I might have three of four triggers all on top of each other.

Comment: But if you only check > it'll keep firing infinitely above that threshold.